# Error trying to make a wrapper of the STL map container

Tags: c++, templates, stl, dictionary, constants

I'm trying to make a wrapper to the STL map container, in order to add a const method to return the value given the key. In map, operator[] isn't const, and find() requires dereferencing to get the value (map.find()->second). I'm basing some of my "research" off of [Idiomatic C++ for reading from a const map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152643/idiomatic-c-for-reading-from-a-const-map) by the way.

The code so far (all inside a single header file):

```
#include <map>
template <typename K, typename V>
class easymap : public std::map<K, V>
{
    //Constructor
    easymap() : std::map<K, V>() {};

    //The get method
    V get(K key)
    {
        std::map<K, V>::const_iterator iter(find(key));
        return iter != end() ? iter->second : V();
    }
};
```

When I try to compile this, I get the following errors:

```
In member function `V easymap::get(K)':
    expected `;' before "iter"
`iter' was not declared in this scope
there are no arguments to `end' that depend on a template parameter, so a declaration of `end' must be available|
(if you use `-fpermissive', G++ will accept your code, but allowing the use of an undeclared name is deprecated)
```

Does how I'm trying to go about doing this make sense? If so, how do I make this work? If not, how would I go about achieving the effect I'm looking for?

Comment: Also have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2396019/c-templates-hides-parent-members) thread.

Comment: Note that the accepted answer in that thread just implements this as a free function. There isn't really that much difference between `map.get(x);` and `get(map, x);` - You are also forgetting that a map has two more template parameters (predicate and allocator).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the template parameters for map, you have to specify `typename` when declaring the iterator (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600936/officially-what-is-typename-for)), and for some reason unknown to me (probably a namespace conflict) you have to use `this` when calling `end()`:

```
template <typename K, typename V>
class easymap : public std::map<K,V>
{
    //Constructor
    easymap() : std::map<K, V>() {};

    //The get method
    V get(K key)
    {
        typename std::map<K, V>::const_iterator iter(find(key));
        return iter != this->end() ? iter->second : V();
    }
};
```

Comment: Regarding the `this`, there are some other ways also. See FAQ item [35.19 Why am I getting errors when my template-derived-class uses a member it inherits from its template-base-class?](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/templates.html#faq-35.19). Cheers & hth.,

Comment: Thanks so much, that worked perfectly! Good information on typename, something I definitely should have read up on by now, as well as the tip to use this->end(), which I agree, makes little sense. G++'s error message on that doesn't help a whole lot either (to me at least)

Answer (score 3):

Do not derive from `std::map`. Rather, wrap a `std::map` instance in your `easymap`, following the composition before inheritance principle. Besides of all the technical reasons, this reflects the design intent much better: provide a simplified API to map hiding the default one:

```
template<typename K, typename V>
class easymap {
 std::map<K, V> mMap;
public:
  V Get(K Key) const {
   // ...
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

It's no a good idea to use STL container as base class. You should have a really good reason to do that and to be very careful.

The reason is, that none of the STL containers have a `virtual` destructor. So, if you have a pointer, for example `std::map<..> *`, that points to your object (that has inherited the `map`), one of the destructors will **not** be called. This is a 100% memory leak.

Related question to this one is: [Is it okay to inherit implementation from STL containers, rather than delegate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2034916/is-it-okay-to-inherit-implementation-from-stl-containers-rather-than-delegate)

Comment: How often do you dynamically allocate an STL container?